# How to correctly launch application using its desktop-file copied to GNOME flashback desktop?

Tags: gnome, .desktop, shortcuts, 20.04, gnome-flashback

I have just installed GNOME FlashBack session on fresh Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Then I opened Applications menu and dragged by mouse some icon (Cheese in my case) from it to the desktop.

[image: Cheese]

The dragged icon does not have real icon and was shown as simple text file. I double-clicked this icon, the text editor was surprisingly opened. Then I did right mouse click on this desktop file and made it executable. Even after this I can't launch this application by double-clicking the icon.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Most likely it is bug...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Public bug was reported to launchpad as [bug 1875317](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1875317).

This functionality will be available soon in *focal-updates* pocket.